# Performance: is_numeric() and is_string() in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, isnumeric

I have a bunch of arrays in an array ex.

```
$array =
         array(
            array(/../),
            array(/../),
            array(/../),
            //upto 100-200 arrays
         );
```

After that, I will use `foreach` to `echo` all of them. There is some checking here whether the `$key` is `is_numeric()` or `is_string()`, for example:

```
array(
   'the_key_here_is_numeric',
   'string' => 'the key is string'
);
```

So I have a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($array as $arr => $arrays) {
   foreach($arrays as $key => $value) {
      if(is_numeric($key)) {
         /.../
      }
      if(is_string($key)) {
         /../
      }
   }
   echo /../;
}
```

When I tested this using `KCacheGrind`, obviously the `is_string()` and `is_numeric()` will be used multiple times, my question is, will this affect the performance? If so, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Because some people here like giving down votes just like that. You must get used to it :(

Comment: Yeah thought so, at least, before they do this, say something, how can a newbie like me get a help when somebody like him/her roaming here. They're not even helping yet they do this.

Comment: I know that. Tell that to them.

Comment: The problem with that is I can't fight back because I do not know who they are and can't report them.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem at the beginning here. So I get used to it :/

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Now I know I am not the only here getting bullied by the big shots. Haha, thanks by the way.

Comment: You are welcome. It is good to know you are not alone ;)

Comment: Please read [Why am I downvoted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react). It is not bullying - there is no need to accuse anyone of it.

Comment: Yes `is_string` and `is_numeric` will be called multiple times but is that a problem? Btw. I assume you know of the `continue` statement to directly continue in the (for, while or do) loop. This shortcut might shave a few ms. of time. But having said that both `is_numeric` and `is_string` are lightingly fast,. Another way would be to find out if there is a way to build your array in such a way that `is_numeric` is not needed if _all_ content is numeric from the start. It gets more a design question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use else. Then condition will be check only once

Not

```
if(is_numeric($key)) {
         /.../
      }
      if(is_string($key)) {
         /../
      }
```

But

```
  if(is_string($key)) {
     /../
  } else {
     /.../
  }
```

Comment: Okay I understand your point, but I do still have question(s) that are not answered, obviously in your code `is_string()` will be called many times, does the `is_string()` will affect the performance if it's called many times?

Comment: There is only max 200 iteration so it will be fine. Now we reduced by half this IFs ;) Beside, what do you want with this keys? Maybe there is better solution

Comment: The arrays may go more than 200, yeah your answer seems to reduce something, I use this to generate `html tags` and `attributes`.

Comment: Can you tell sth more about this. Right now it is hard to help you more than I did it.

Comment: What is sth? here is the example of the array `array('div', 'class' => 'div_class')`.

Comment: sth = Can you tell something more about this?

Comment: I gave you an example.

Comment: It is okay now, there is no problem now (I think), so I accepted your answer because it helps me.

Comment: Nospor, I will ask an additional question, is this kind of code good practice for production? Right now I am producing a hundred to 500 arrays.

Comment: @DumbQuestion I still do not know the all context of your problem so this is hard to say. For now 500 array seems a little to bit - but as I said, I do not know all context.

Comment: This is my example code: `$header/$body/$footer = array(array('div', 'class' => 'div_class'), array(/.contents goes here so on./), array('div' => 'end'))` `$display = array($header, $body, $footer);`. Then, I will use a 3 nested `foreach()` loop to output all of the html contents.

Comment: But I need to know **why** do you have such structure and **why** do you need it.

Comment: That way there is no overwritten into key and I use it to generate html tags, attributes, etc.

Comment: But why do you have such structure? Why do you build your html code in this way?

Comment: For me, it is more readable than just echo `<div class="">...</div>` all the time, and when you use `View Page Source`, the codes will be hard to read because the output will have no spaces or new line.

Comment: Ouch... you've chosen really really bad way. Try to read about templates system like Twig or just simple template in php code (It is popular in ZF). What you are doing now it is really **bad** idea.

Comment: Oh okay, I am sorry I am not very a programmer guy, I just want to make my codes more faster for users. Is there any alternative for this? Before I asked this I search through here how to generate `Html` codes in `php` and most of them make a function that will use a `foreach` loop to output the `html` codes. Should I use this?

Comment: I have no idea why someone would like to use foreach to generate html code. Well, except your idea with arrays of course ;) 
If you do not want to use templates, just use echo and add \n at the end if you really want to have nice source, eg: echo '<div>blabla</div>'."\n";

Comment: Oh, that's right. Thank you. I will use that for dynamic `html` and by the way I tried to use this and the response times reduced upto 1s